# Function slideToggle not detecting the previous open/close state of the div script only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Function slideToggle not detecting the previous open/close state of the div script only javascript because in jquery no problem but I only want javascript.

When I click on the second button the div opens and this closes right away as the script does not include detect the state I think but I do not see how to modify the javascript script to prevent the bug.
I want each button to open and close its own div.

current result :
https://jsfiddle.net/vincent1890/5fje4zwv/2/

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
            <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> -->
            <style type="text/css">
            /* Just to play with animations */
            .header {
              padding: 10px 16px;
              background: #555;
              color: #f1f1f1;
              font-size: 0.835em;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              letter-spacing: 0.125em;
              font-weight: bold;
            }
            
            /* Some Generic styles */
            body {
              text-align: center;
              font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
              color: #444;
              line-height: 1.6;
            }
            /* CSS styles "+ OPTIONS ..." */
            .bouton-deplier {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
                background: #000;
                padding: 5px 10px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .montexte {
                padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
            }
    
            #mdiv {
                height: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                border-radius: 0px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                background-color: #ef1;
                margin-bottom: 0em;
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
            }
            #mdiv2 {
                height: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                border-radius: 0px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                background-color: #ef1;
                margin-bottom: 0em;
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body onload="chg_item()">
            <div class="header" id="myHeader" >
                <button class="bouton-deplier" id="mbtn" onclick="slideToggle('mdiv', 50);">+ Options autres</button>
                <button class="bouton-deplier" id="mbtn2" onclick="slideToggle('mdiv2', 100);">+ Optionnel (Telephonie Audioconf)</button>
                <div id="mdiv">
                    <div class="montexte">
                        <label for="UidText">Uid (User):</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ChoisirUid" onfocus="this.value=''" onchange="chg_item()">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mdiv2">
                    <div class="montexte">
                        <label for="TelNumberText">Num Tel (User):</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ChoisirTelNumber" onfocus="this.value=''" onchange="chg_item()">
                        <br>
                        <label for="NomPrenomText">Nom Prenom :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ChoisirNomPrenom" onfocus="this.value=''" onchange="chg_item()">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        <script>
        var slideOpen = false;
        //var heightChecked = false;
        var initHeight = 60;
        var intval = null;
    
        function slideToggle(NameDiv, Height) {
            var initHeight = Height;
            
            window.clearInterval(intval);
            var NameDiv = document.getElementById(NameDiv);
            /*
            if(!heightChecked) {
                initHeight = NameDiv.offsetHeight;
                heightChecked = true;
            }
            */
            if(slideOpen) {
                var h = initHeight;
                slideOpen = false;
                intval = setInterval(function(){
                    h--;
                    NameDiv.style.height = h + 'px';
                    if(h <= 0)
                        window.clearInterval(intval);
                    }, 1
                );
            }
            else {
                var h = 0;
                slideOpen = true;
                intval = setInterval(function(){
                    h++;
                    NameDiv.style.height = h + 'px';
                    if(h >= initHeight)
                        window.clearInterval(intval);
                    }, 1
                );
            }
        }
        </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <button id="btn1" class="btn" onclick="clickHandler('first')">First tab</button>
  <button id="btn2" class="btn" onclick="clickHandler('second')">Second tab</button>
  
  <div id="first" class="data hidden">Hello</div>
  <div id="second" class="data hidden">World!</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function clickHandler(id) {
  toggle("data");
  
  const div = document.getElementById(id);
  div.classList.add("shown");
  div.classList.remove("hidden");
}

function toggle(className) {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    const elm = elements[i];
    if (elm.classList.contains("shown")) {
      elm.classList.remove("shown")
      elm.classList.add("hidden")
    }
  }
}
```

This handler changes every element currently shown to hidden, then executes the clickHandler and shows the button only which was clicked.

You can add more css to this for better visuals.

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqeu6j05/2/)

Comment: Hello @kmp thank for help but is it possible to modify and how your script so that each button opens and closes independently ca own div?

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Don't forget to close the question (accept one of the answers) so others won't spam solutions. :D and also, an upvote would be nice ^_^

Comment: To complete the script how to add a third button allowing the closing of all two div or reapply a second time on one of the two button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this with jquery

```js
$(".bouton-deplier").click(function() {
  var btnID = $(this).attr('id');

  if ($(".textContent:visible").is(':visible')) {
    $(".textContent:visible").slideUp(0, function() {
      $("." + btnID + ".textContent").slideDown("slow");
    });
  } else {
    $("." + btnID + ".textContent").slideDown("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
        .header {
          padding: 10px 16px;
          background: #555;
          color: #f1f1f1;
          font-size: 0.835em;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          letter-spacing: 0.125em;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        /* Some Generic styles */
        body {
          text-align: center;
          font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          color: #444;
          line-height: 1.6;
        }
        /* CSS styles "+ OPTIONS ..." */
        .bouton-deplier {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            background: #000;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .montexte {
            padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
        }

        .mbtn {
            display:none;
            height: 60px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            border-radius: 0px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            background-color: #ef1;
            margin-bottom: 0em;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
        }
        .mbtn2 {
            display:none;
            height: 60px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            border-radius: 0px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            background-color: #ef1;
            margin-bottom: 0em;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header" id="myHeader" >
            <button class="bouton-deplier" id="mbtn">+ Options autres</button>
            <button class="bouton-deplier" id="mbtn2">+ Optionnel (Telephonie Audioconf)</button>
            <div class="mbtn textContent">
                <div class="montexte">
                    <label for="UidText">Uid (User):</label>
                    <input type="text" id="ChoisirUid" onfocus="this.value=''" onchange="chg_item()">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mbtn2 textContent">
                <div class="montexte">
                    <label for="TelNumberText">Num Tel (User):</label>
                    <input type="text" id="ChoisirTelNumber" onfocus="this.value=''" onchange="chg_item()">
                    <br>
                    <label for="NomPrenomText">Nom Prenom :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="ChoisirNomPrenom" onfocus="this.value=''" onchange="chg_item()">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello @The_Death_Raw thank for your aswers but jquery no problem but I want only script javascript.